# cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type 'system.data.datatable'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a `Login` table in SQL Server 2008 and I want to check for a valid user in DataColumn.

I was trying to retrieve value from DataColumn by indexing, but got the error..

> cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type 'system.data.datatable'.

Here is the code:

```
 string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DRZare;Integrated Security=true;";
 SqlConnection LOGINCONNECTION = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

 string commandText = "select * from Login where UserName = @User and Password = @Pass";
 SqlCommand cmdlogin = new SqlCommand(commandText,    LOGINCONNECTION);

 cmdlogin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", TextBox5.Text);
 cmdlogin.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass",TextBox6.Text);

 LOGINCONNECTION.Open();
 DataTable logintable = new DataTable();
 logintable.Load(cmdlogin.ExecuteReader());

 for (int i = 0; i < logintable.Rows.Count; i++ )
 {
     User = Convert.ToString(logintable[i]["UserName"]);
     string Pass = Convert.ToString(logintable[i]["Password"]);
 }
```

Help me out.

Comment: DataTable has no indexer. Check `for (DataRow row in loginTable.Rows )
                {
                     User = Convert.ToString(row["UserName"]); ...
                   
                }`

Comment: Please **DO NEVER** store a user's password in **CLEAR TEXT** in a database table!

Answer (score 4):

Error message says clearly where is the problem. You can't use indexer on DataTable. But you can use it with DataRow.

Change to:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in loginTable.Rows )
 { 
     string User = Convert.ToString(row["UserName"]);
     string Pass = Convert.ToString(row["Password"]);
 }
```

Comment: In this foreach loop, I can't use var row. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. The code was changed into this and now it works correctly.

```
string User = Convert.ToString(logintable.Rows[i]["UserName"]);
                string Pass = Convert.ToString(logintable.Rows[i]["Password"]
```